# CSS of WP blog part of my website does not work well in IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, doctype

i would really appreciate if some could tell me what the problem is... My website http://webdesign.igorlaszlo.com works well in IE9, also its blog part http://webdesign.igorlaszlo.com/blog/ which is built by wp twentyeleven child theme.

The styling in IE11 my wp blog does not work well. Why ?

The html5 doctype of both parts :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js ie ie6 lte8 lte7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js ie ie7 lte8 lte7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js ie ie8 lte8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <html lang="fr-FR" style="" class=" js no-touch history">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

My second question is about those classes which are indicated in it : no-js, ie6, ie7, etc. Where do they come from ? I copied these codes from other websites in the beginning of the use of html5 because i saw them in many html pages... If i understood well from the web, it is something from Modernizr ? It includes the css which contain those classes ? 
And what is Boilerplate ? I did not understand what is what in the history...

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and i publish here, maybe someone will have the same problem in IE versions...

In the `<head>` i had invalid meta tags which blocked several scripts and css3 styles in IE versions (except IE9), for example :

```
<meta content='fr-FR' http-equiv='Content-Language'/>
<meta content='IE=EmulateIE7' http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible'/>
```

You can check it iby W3.org validator : http://validator.w3.org/

Good chance !